# How do you keep the state of your activity when switching between them?

Tags: android

I have added a button that allows you to switch to another activity, however when I return to the main activity the data entered disappears as it is loading a new one. Would it be possible to return it to the state it was before switching to the other activity?

Comment: It really depends on how you have built it. Post some code and explain what you'd like to happen

Comment: What code would you like to see of it, I basically have an app that gets the users location and prints out the closest transport (in a text format) however there is a button that loads up a second activity that produces the results as a map. From here the user is able to go back into the main activity through a back button. However, this opens it as a new activity. Instead, I want it to appear the same as when the user left it to look at the map. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Perhaps show us all the code related to the back button :)

Comment: public void launchFirstActivity(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    }